# SQL expression ArcPy date format

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql, datetime, typeerror

I'm trying to use `definitionquery` to keep entities where date is smaller or equal to a certain date ( variable entered by the user). The Variable and the field in the table are formatted as dates. when running my script the error is a concatenate error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\zoomDate.py", line 10, in <module>
    lyr.definitionQuery = '"start_date" <= ' + "'"+arcpy.GetParameter(0)+"'"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str
```

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
mapx = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers()[2]
Date = arcpy.GetParameter(0)

lyr.definitionQuery = '"start_date" <= ' + "'"+arcpy.GetParameter(0)+"'"
lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT')[0]

mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, False, True))
```

I was using `GetParameterAsText` to run almost the same script on string variables and it work flawlessly.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like greetings and thanks in your posts.

Comment: Why did you stop using `AsText`? The error is straight forward, you cant "add" data objects and strings.

Comment: I don’t use `as text` because the field is a date format

Comment: Text is the only format in which dates can be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get past the error you're receiving is to cast the date object to a string.

In your example, this looks like  (`str()`):

`lyr.definitionQuery = '"start_date" <= ' + "'"+str(arcpy.GetParameter(0))+"'"`

> start_date <= *some date*

However, I'll caution without knowing your actual date input, this might not work as the date format may not match your data, thus it'll never compare properly. This is almost certain to be true if your start_date is a *string* instead of an actual date. In this case, you'll probably want to look up how to [format dates](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime).

If you have an actual **Date** field, try the following syntax, noting the *timestamp* keyword

```
dateCompare = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
lyr.definitionQuery = "start_date <= timestamp '{}'".format(dateCompare)
```